# multiple select inside dropwdownlist mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need multi select  checkbox inside dropdown list mvc

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Product" class="required">Product</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("SellerSKUid", null, new { @id = "txtOeCustomer",@name = "SellerSKUid", @class =
            "form-control", placeholder = "Select SellerSKUid"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Product" class="required">Product</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("SellerSKUid", null, new { @id = "txtOeCustomer",@name = "SellerSKUid", @class =
            "form-control", placeholder = "Select SellerSKUid"})
</div>
```

Comment: Use Html.ListBox instead of DropDownList. Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/P0CoT1

Comment: Thank you..But i need multiple select checkbox inside the dropdown.

Comment: that isn't possible. You can't put a checkbox inside a select option. Browsers don't support it. The user can just select each option they want from the listbox (on a device with a keyboard they hold down Ctrl to select multiple options while clicking). If you really need checkboxes for some reason then re-think your UI a bit.